# Galaxy s5 stuck in reboot loop after root

Tags: root-access, reboot

Today I tried to root my galaxy s5 with Kingo Root for android. My phone restarted during the rooting process, but it keeps looping over and over. I have tried resetting the cache and even factory resetting it (by booting it up in recovery mode), but after the reset the same reboot logo appears. Any help at this point would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Your device is *bricked*, this means that unless you have a **custom recovery** installed then you cannot access your device. If your phone is still under warranty, then you may be able to get it fixed for a low cost, as this is a quick fix with the right equipment.

If you want to attempt the fix yourself, here are some articles:

[MakeUseOf](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-recover-bricked-android-phone/)

[XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2386239)